# Python style: more concise way to rename a variable while checking it is not null

Tags: python

In Python, I often find myself writing the following slightly unwieldy bit of code:

```
if data['name'] is not None:
    name = data['name']
    # do stuff with 'name' over many lines
    # hence bothering to rename it at all!
    $('#myname').text(name)...
```

Can the first two lines be collapsed into one, perhaps all inside the condition statement?

Comment: Umm, why don't you directly use `data['name']`?

Comment: This is a confusing example.  The '#do stuff with name' line implies that you want to do more than just the assignment, so you can't get rid of the if block.  Also, you'll get an exception if 'name' is not in data.  You'll want to use get, unless you know for sure it's there.

Comment: Yes, I want to do more than just the assignment. I don't want to use `data['name']` because it gets unwieldy over many lines, especially when variables have more complicated names than `data['name']`! Have edited the question to be a bit clearer.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, but did you just mix python and jquery? :)

Comment: @Chris er yes. OK. Sleep time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way to do it in one line.  I'd recommend sticking to what you're already doing to improve readability:

```
for name in (data['name'],) if data['name'] else ():
    print name
```

You can use else with a for loop and it will flow the same as an if statement.  It just looks odd and is less straightforward than just using an if.

Comment: Thanks. I've actually used @lig's answer for legibility as you suggest, but it's good to know how to do it in one line.

Comment: @Richard good to know! Thanks for accepting the solution you will really use:)

Answer (score 3):

in some cases e.g. string names you can simply do something like this

```
name = data['name'] or ''
```

A generic way is it to use if-else shorthand e.g.

```
name = data['name'] if data['name'] is not None else ''
```

or if you prefer (i prefer above one as main assignment is at start and exceptional case at end)

```
name = '' if data['name'] is None else data['name']
```

Comment: I use the second form all the time, it's more explicit than `dict.get()` IMO.

Comment: Thanks, this is neater than the way I was doing it, though I still have to write `if name` in the following line, so it's no shorter.

Comment: @Aphex `data['name'] if data['name'] is not None else ''` is not an alternative for dict.get() as it will raise KeyError if there is no 'name' in data.

Answer (score 3):

You could do :

```
try:
   name = data['name']
except KeyError:
   pass
```

use the key, if it is not in the dict, exception will be raised and catched. (refer to [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp))

Or use the [dict.get](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method :

```
name = data.get("name", "")
```

Comment: It is not very good practice to rely on exception handling as it takes much more resources than .get() method.

Answer (score 3):

The right way:

```
name = data.get('name')

if name:
     # your code for name here
```